# Auto Load data with loading spinner when reach 10 article with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, infinity

I have an HTML code, And I want to limit the article to 10 and auto load when the scroll is reached the last article, also show loading spinner. It looks like need jquery or javascript to make it works.
I hope that I could make it auto load when reaching 10 articles with loading spinner.

Here is my HTML code :

```html
<div class="container">
                <article class="post">
                    <div class="row lined">
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h1 class="no-padding heading-num">2</h1></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8 no-side-padding">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h2>Ada Lowongan Kerja Terbaru di Kemenkes, Mau?</h2></a>
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration source"><h4>Liputan6.com</h4></a>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 no-side-padding">
                            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/80x80/" class="responsive" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="post">
                    <div class="row lined">
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h1 class="no-padding heading-num">3</h1></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8 no-side-padding">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h2>Perhatikan Penampilan Ketika Wawancara Kerja, Ini Tipsnya</h2></a>
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration source"><h4>Liputan6.com</h4></a>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 no-side-padding">
                            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/80x80/" class="responsive" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="post">
                    <div class="row lined">
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h1 class="no-padding heading-num">4</h1></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8 no-side-padding">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h2>Berdasarkan Zodiak, Ini Wanita yang Jadi Pasangan Terbaik</h2></a>
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration source"><h4>Liputan6.com</h4></a>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 no-side-padding">
                            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/80x80/" class="responsive" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="post">
                    <div class="row lined">
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h1 class="no-padding heading-num">5</h1></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8 no-side-padding">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h2>Generasi Ini Paling Rentan Bertengkar Soal Uang dengan Pasangan</h2></a>
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration source"><h4>Liputan6.com</h4></a>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 no-side-padding">
                            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/80x80/" class="responsive" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="post">
                    <div class="row lined">
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h1 class="no-padding heading-num">6</h1></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8 no-side-padding">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h2>Gaya Andalan Syahrini Setelah Berhasil Berbobot 47 Kilogram</h2></a>
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration source"><h4>Liputan6.com</h4></a>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 no-side-padding">
                            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/80x80/" class="responsive" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="post">
                    <div class="row lined">
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h1 class="no-padding heading-num">7</h1></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8 no-side-padding">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h2>Parfum Bertahan Seharian? Tidak Sulit dengan 8 Cara Ini</h2></a>
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration source"><h4>Liputan6.com</h4></a>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 no-side-padding">
                            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/80x80/" class="responsive" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="post">
                    <div class="row lined">
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h1 class="no-padding heading-num">8</h1></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8 no-side-padding">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h2>Siaran Tanpa Makeup, Newscaster Ini Tuai Pujian</h2></a>
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration source"><h4>Liputan6.com</h4></a>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 no-side-padding">
                            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/80x80/" class="responsive" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="post">
                    <div class="row lined">
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h1 class="no-padding heading-num">9</h1></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8 no-side-padding">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h2>Jakarta Buka Kompetisi Balet Internasional Asian Grand Prix</h2></a>
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration source"><h4>Liputan6.com</h4></a>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 no-side-padding">
                            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/80x80/" class="responsive" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>

                <article class="post">
                    <div class="row lined">
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h1 class="no-padding heading-num">10</h1></a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8 no-side-padding">
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration"><h2>Drone Ikut Berlenggak Lenggok di Panggung Runway Dolce & Gabanna</h2></a>
                            <a href="" class="no-decoration source"><h4>Liputan6.com</h4></a>    
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3 no-side-padding">
                            <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/80x80/" class="responsive" alt="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
```

Comment: You can do this with use of php and ajax

Comment: More specifically, you will want to create a web service of some kind to generate the new content, and use ajax to load and dynamically add it to your html.